# zend-form-validation

Tags: zend-form

I have made form in zend and add validation to it as below

```
$firstname = $this->createElement('text','firstname');
$firstname->setLabel('First Name:')
              ->setRequired(true);
```

Validation is working and giving error message-> 'Value is required and can't be empty.'

But I want that It must say ->  'First Name is required and can't be empty.'

I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to have one validation, you can do this:

```
$firstname = $this->createElement('text','firstname');
$firstname->setLabel('First Name:')
          ->setRequired(true);
          ->addErrorMessage('First Name is required and can't be empty.');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
$firstname = $this->createElement('text', 'firstname');
$firstname = $this->getElement('firstname')
                  ->setRequired(true)
                  ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true);
$firstname->getValidator('NotEmpty')
          ->setMessage('First Name is required and can't be empty.');
```